# Non residential lease: early termination

Tags: florida, lease

What is the controlling law regarding early termination requested by a Florida NON-residential tenant?  Assume the lease does not specify a termination clause (does not specify notification / early penalty etc.

- What are the obligations of the tenant?

**Update:** [Florida Landlord & Tenant hyperlink](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0083/0083.html): I am unable to find anything that answers said question and can not be certain that this is the only controlling law.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a term in the lease allowing it, the general common law rule which very likely applies in Florida in a non-residential lease (to which no industry specific regulatory law, e.g. for a nuclear power plant or a land lease) applies, is that it may only be terminated: (1) by the mutual agreement of the parties, or (2) when elected by a party seeking to terminate the lease for a material breach by the party not seeking to terminate the lease (e.g. non-payment of rent or condemnation of the premises in an eminent domain action).

Comment: @ohwillike Would abandonment of the property be equivalent to your cited reason (2)?

Comment: @gatorback Usually, abandonment of the property only potentially terminates the lease when the lease expressly makes abandonment of the property a condition of default. But, there are lots of potential factual nuances involved.